# How to count number of ObjectId occurrences in an array of ObjectIds' and attach the result to each document that is being returned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Tag` schema:

```
const TagSchema = new Schema({
  label: {type: String, unique: true, minlength: 2},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: null},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: new Date(), required: true},
  createdBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', default: null}
});

const Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema);
```

Then I have a `Page` schema:

```
const PageSchema = new Schema({
  tags: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'}], default: [], maxlength: 5}
});

const Page = mongoose.model('Page', PageSchema);
```

As you can see it contains a `Tag` reference in its `tags` array.

Now what I need to do is when I fetch all tags via `/tags`, I also need to count the number of times each tag is used in all `Page`s.

So if a `Tag` is used `2`times across all `Page`s, it should set an `.occurrences` property on the returned tag. For example this would be a response from `/tags`:

```
[
 {_id: '192398dsf7asdsdds8f7d', label: 'tag 1', updatedAt: '20170102', createdAt: '20170101', createdBy: '01238198dsad8s7d78ad7', occurrences: 2},
 {_id: '19239asdasd8dsf7ds8f7d', label: 'tag 2', updatedAt: '20170102', createdAt: '20170101', createdBy: '01238198dsad8s7d78ad7', occurrences: 1},
 {_id: '192398dsf7zxccxads8f7d', label: 'tag 1', updatedAt: '20170102', createdAt: '20170101', createdBy: '01238198dsad8s7d78ad7', occurrences: 5},
]
```

I would have imagined that I could achieve this pretty easily in a mongoose `pre('find')` hook like this:

```
TagSchema.pre('find', function() {

  Page.count({tags: this._id}, (err, total) => {
    this.occurrences = total;
  });
});
```

However, there are two problems here:

- `Page.count` throws an error saying it's not a function, which I don't understand why because I use it somewhere else perfectly fine. And `Page` has been imported properly. Suggesting that you can't use `count` in a hook or something similar.
- `this` is not the `Tag` document.

So I guess that the way I am going about this is completely wrong.

Since I am a novice in MongoDB maybe someone can provide me with a better, working, solution to my problem?

Comment: here  `Page.count({tags: this._id}, (err, total) => {`
    `this.occurrences = total;`
  `});`  what you want to do ?

Comment: @hardy I don't understand your question.

Comment: the `.pre` code which you have written above is for what purpose ? basically  what you want to do when you make query of `find` in tag Collection ? because pre is use as middle-wares in mongoose

Comment: @hardy Everything is already explained very thoroughly in the question..

Comment: according to [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) `this` refers to the query and not to the object. why not just get the count in the `find` function itself? As for the `count` is not a function please provide more info on the code as i tried it and it works fine, is all the code in one file? if not can you provide the full schema ?

Comment: @M.Sallam Doing it in the find function would require me to loop over each document manually, which feels really slow and ugly solution. So setting it on the schema itself would take care of this automatically for each tag, which feels like a better way to go about it. Each schema is in their separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Page.aggregate([ 
{
  $unwind:"$tags"
},
{
  $group:{ 
    _id:"$tags", 
    occurrences:{$sum:1}
  }
},
{
  $lookup:{ //get data for each tag
    from:"tags",
    localField:"_id",
    foreignField:"_id",
    as:"tagsData"
  }
},
{
$project:{
  tagData:{$arrayElemAt: [ "$tagsData", 0 ]},
  occurrences:1
}
}
{
  $addFields:{ 
    "tagData._id":"$_id",
    "tagData.occurrences":"$occurrences"
  }
},
{
   $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$tagData" }
}
])
```

Comment: I have added comments . please check

Comment: And where would I put this? In a hook or where I do the find? Also I just get an empty array from that, I would expect a number or an array with something I can use length on.

Comment: First run this query on directly to mongodb console with your appropriate collection names in mongodb . like instead of Page there should be pages collections and same goes with tags.
If you get right answer then use same in your code or api

Comment: Ok so this almost works now, however, I want the `occurrences` property to be merged with the entire `Tag` document rather than having just the `_id` of the tag being added to the result. So instead of `{_id: 'foo', occurrences: 2}` it would be `{_id: 'foo', label: 'test', occurrences: 2, createdAt: 'some-date'}`. How do I do that?

Comment: add that property in $addFields stage . Do one thing check output of every stage sequentially. and you will understand it. And also if you can show me exact output and your schema then I can help

Comment: I added the entire `Tag` schema, see top of question. Also the expected output example has been updated. The thing with `$addFields` is that `label` is never added in your example. Since `tags` is an array of `_id`s I assume you must populate the array first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160584/discussion-between-chrillewoodz-and-shubham).

Answer (score 0):

Ok first, you need [getQuery()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-getQuery) this allows you to access the properties that you are finding the `tag` with. so if you find the tag by `_id`, you will have access to it in the `pre` hook by `this.getQuery()._id`

Second, you are going to need to use the "Parallel" middleware, can be found in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). This allows the find method to wait until the `done` function is called, so it is gonna wait until the tag is updated with the new occurrences number.

As the object can no be accessed inn the `pre` hook as it is yet to be found, you are going to have to use `findOneAndUpdate` method in the `pre` hook.

So the code should look like :

The `find` method :

```
Tag.find({ _id: "foo"}, function (err, foundTag) {
  console.log(foundTag)
})
```

The `pre` hook :

```
TagSchema.pre('find', true, function (next, done) {
  mongoose.models['Page'].count({ tags: this.getQuery()._id }, (err, total) => {
    mongoose.models['Tag'].findOneAndUpdate({ _id: this.getQuery()._id }, { occurrences: total }, function () {
      next()
      done()
    })
  });
});
```